# Lagging and leading variables non-panel data Stata

Tags: time-series, stata

For the purpose of an event study, I would like to create lagging and leading variables in my data set. Unfortunately, my data is not in a balanced panel format.

My data set looks as:

```
clear

input id year month binary str7 implement
28845421 2007 3 0 2008-1
29118744 2018 10 1 2012-6
29118744 2016 7 1 2016-7
29183010 2019 3 1 2010-1
29320027 2013 3 0 2015-2
end

. list

     +---------------------------------------------+
     |       id   year   month   binary   implem~t |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. | 2.88e+07   2007       3        0     2008-1 |
  2. | 2.91e+07   2018      10        1     2012-6 |
  3. | 2.91e+07   2016       7        1     2016-7 |
  4. | 2.92e+07   2019       3        1     2010-1 |
  5. | 2.93e+07   2013       3        0     2015-2 |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```

The variable `binary` equals 1 at the point when its `year` and `month` combination has reached the `implement` date. Each observation is represented by an identifier `id`.

The goal is to create lagging and leading variables of the `binary`: `binary-5`, `binary-4`, `...`, `binary+1`, `binary+2`, `...`. In other words, I want to shift `implement` by n years of increments / decrement to create the new binary variables.

How can I create such variables in Stata?

Comment: Please follow the `stata` wiki and give a data example using Stata code. Contrary to the claim here your dataset appears equivalent to panel data with identifier variable `ID` and a monthly date variable that can be constructed from `Year` and `Month`. However. it is not clear whether your implementation date variables are, or should be,, string variables, numeric variables with value labels or numeric variables with date display format. That is why a data example in proper form is needed for useful suggestions of code.

Comment: Thanks, @NickCox. I edited the post.

Comment: You can get monthly date by `gen mdate = ym(year, month)` and implementation date in comparable form by `gen idate = monthly(implement, "YM")`. I don't understand the rest of your question.